# Julian dates in R chron versus US Naval Observatory

Tags: r, date

Several previous posts have asked how to obtain Julian dates in `R`.  One post in particular really wanted ordinal dates and I posted an answer:

[Convert a date vector into Julian day in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414847/convert-a-date-vector-into-julian-day-in-r)

I pointed out that my answer really provided ordinal dates rather than Julian dates.  Today I tried to modify my answer to show how to obtain true Julian dates and I became confused when using the `R` package `chron`.

Below is `R` code that generates a set of random dates and then attempts to obtain the corresponding Julian dates.  Initially I tried to use the `R` package `chron` to create the Julian dates and the US Naval Observatory website to check my answers:

http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php

My answers did not match.

Eventually I was able to obtain Julian dates that match those from the US Naval Observatory (after rounding off the decimal place) by using an equation from Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

My question is: what am I doing wrong in `chron`?  How to I get Julian dates in `chron` that match those obtained from the US Naval Observatory or that match those obtained with an equation from Wikipedia?

Thank you for any advice.

Here is my R code:

```
set.seed(1234)
n.dates <- 10

day   <- sample(        25, n.dates, replace = TRUE)
month <- sample(        11, n.dates, replace = TRUE) 
year  <- sample(c(-4714:-1, 1:2014), n.dates, replace = TRUE)
year.b <- ifelse(year < 1, year+1, year)

a <- floor((14 - month) / 12)
y <- year.b + 4800 - a
m <- month + 12 * a - 3

#
# from Wikipedia:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day
#

julian1 <- day + floor((153*m + 2)/5) + 365*y + floor(y/4) - floor(y/100) + floor(y/400) - 32045
julian2 <- day + floor((153*m + 2)/5) + 365*y + floor(y/4) - 32083

my.data <- data.frame(month, day, year, year.b, a, y, m, julian1, julian2, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(chron)
options(chron.origin = c(month=1, day=1, year= -4713))

my.data$my.julian <- julian(my.data$month, my.data$day, my.data$year)
my.data

#
# Note that julian2 matches the US Naval Observatory rounding off the decimal place.
#
#   month day  year year.b a    y m julian1 julian2 my.julian
#1      8   3 -2584  -2583 0 2217 5  777853  777832    777815
#2      6  16 -2678  -2677 0 2123 3  743472  743450    743434
#3      4  16 -3644  -3643 0 1157 1  390587  390558    390549
#4     11  16 -4445  -4444 0  356 8   98242   98207     98203
#5      4  22 -3242  -3241 0 1559 1  537420  537394    537382
#6     10  17   740    740 0 5540 7 1991629 1991633   1991956
#7      4   1 -1178  -1177 0 3623 1 1291260 1291249   1291222
#8      3   6  1440   1440 0 6240 0 2247074 2247083   2247401
#9      3  17   880    880 0 5680 0 2042550 2042554   2042877
#10     3  13 -4407  -4406 0  394 0  111873  111838    111835
#
# According to the US Naval Observatory website, the julian dates are:
#
# The Julian date for BCE  2584 August    3 00:00:00.0 UT is JD  777831.500000
# The Julian date for BCE  2678 June     16 00:00:00.0 UT is JD  743449.500000
# The Julian date for BCE  3644 April    16 00:00:00.0 UT is JD  390557.500000
# The Julian date for BCE  4445 November 16 00:00:00.0 UT is JD   98206.500000
# The Julian date for BCE  3242 April    22 00:00:00.0 UT is JD  537393.500000
# The Julian date for CE    740 October  17 00:00:00.0 UT is JD 1991632.500000
# The Julian date for BCE  1177 April     1 00:00:00.0 UT is JD 1291614.500000
# The Julian date for CE   1440 March     6 00:00:00.0 UT is JD 2247082.500000
# The Julian date for CE    880 March    17 00:00:00.0 UT is JD 2042553.500000
# The Julian date for BCE  4407 March    13 00:00:00.0 UT is JD  111837.500000
#
```