# Loop over dates in R

Tags: r, date, for-loop

I want to loop over a series of dates in R. Here's some sample code:

```
myDates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-03"), by = "day")
myDates[1]
class(myDates[1])
```

This creates a vector of dates, and I confirm this by printing and checking the class of the first element.

However, when I run this loop:

```
for (myDate in myDates) print(myDate)
```

I get this output:

```
[1] 18262
[1] 18263
[1] 18264
```

Having checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610271/looping-over-dates-with-r) question I've got some workarounds to solve my immediate issue, but can anyone explain to me why this happens, and if there's a simple way to iterate directly over a vector of dates?

Comment: Can you tell what your ultimate goal is?

Comment: While I agree, that is puzzling (as some things in R *are*), you can do `for (myDate in as.list(myDates)) print(myDate)` and it works as you might expect. (There are several times in R that a vector is un-classes, including `ifelse` and similar. This is apparently one of those cases.)

Comment: Another reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572195/how-to-display-real-dates-in-a-loop-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

The reason has been explained by @r2evans in the comments of your post. Actually you have a couple of methods to circumvent the issue, e.g.,

```
> d <- Map(print,myDates)
[1] "2020-01-01"
[1] "2020-01-02"
[1] "2020-01-03"
```

or

```
> for (myDate in as.character(myDates)) print(myDate)
[1] "2020-01-01"
[1] "2020-01-02"
[1] "2020-01-03"
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding, I think the top method is similar to r2evans suggestion to coerce it to a list. The second one actually doesn't suit my case because I do need to preserve the date type within the loop...