# for loop not printing a result

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run this code, from which I want to get a "happy Birthday!" printed out

```
start_date <- as.Date("2025-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2025-01-01")

for (current_date in seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = "days")) 
{if(as.character(current_date) == "2025-01-01"){print("Happy Birthday!")}}
```

the current_date is becoming an object with a weird numerical value, and after many trials on making it working, I didn't get my message yet. Any advice!

Comment: This question seems very similar to this one. Do the comments and answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858296/loop-over-dates-in-r

Comment: @r2evans's comment in the question above gets to the heart of it. `for()` is one a few functions in R that strip the class information from vectors. Dates in R are fundamentally integers measuring the days since 1970-01-01, with a class that tells R to treat them as dates, so when you put that in a `for` loop the vector is converted to integers like 20089. It looks like using `as.list(seq.Date(....))` might be the simplest workaround.

Comment: Or `if (as.Date(current_date) == "2025-01-01")`

Comment: Note also that in your example, start_date and end_date are the same date, so your sequence length = 1.

Comment: Both of these return TRUE: `for (d in as.Date("2025-01-01")) {print(d == as.Date("2025-01-01")); print(as.Date(d) == "2025-01-01")}` The first compares integer to Date but the second one implies that Date class objects can tolerate comparison with strings. (NB @LTyrone sequence length is not the issue)

Comment: @Tobo - I know, raising the point as it is a bad example. No point creating a sequence if its length is 1 :)

Comment: Well it's certainly _minimal_ ;)

Comment: To summarize, `for()` strips the `Date` class from your date sequence, turning it into 20089. In R's equality rules, `20089 == as.Date("2025-01-01")` (same value but different class) but `as.character(20089) == "20089"` and `"20089" != as.Date("2025-01-01")`.

Comment: @JonSpring Yes but also `as.Date(20089) == "2025-01-01"` i.e. Date class equality method allows a character representation on the right

Comment: Also will you write this up? I know it's probably a duplicate but I can well imagine referring back to this once I've forgotten it all, which will be in about ten minutes. Also, nice first question @AhmedSalahHassan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a dupe or near-dupe of [Loop over dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858296/loop-over-dates-in-r). In both cases, we see that the `for()` function removes the Date class from a vector, turning it into numeric data.

```
> for(a in as.Date("2025-01-01")) { print(a) }
[1] 20089
> as.Date("1970-01-01") + 20089
[1] "2025-01-01"
```

This can result in unexpected comparisons within the loop. Let's compare some different forms of the same data, along with their class.

```
> (chr <- "2025-01-01")           # character
[1] "2025-01-01"     
> (dt <- as.Date(chr))            # Date
[1] "2025-01-01"     
> (num <- as.numeric(dt))         # numeric
[1] 20089            
> (num_chr <- as.character(num))  # character
[1] "20089"
```

When R tests for equality, some type coercions are performed, but they don't work for all forms of this data. In the four steps above, it works to compare one step to the next, but  the answer is FALSE or an error if we skip a step. The original question compares `as.character(current_date) == "2025-01-01"` which is like the fifth example below.

```
chr == dt       # TRUE
dt == num       # TRUE
num == num_chr  # TRUE

chr == num      # FALSE
chr == num_chr  # FALSE <-- OP example

dt == num_chr   # Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

As noted in the comments, this could be solved in a few ways, including:

1. use `for (current_date in as.list(seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by = "days")))` in the first line. `for()` coerces the vector seq.Date into numeric, but it doesn't coerce it if it's preserved as a list.
2. use `if(current_date == as.Date("2025-01-01"))` in the equality test. R can leap the gap between 20089 and `as.Date("2025-01-01")`, equivalent to the `dt == num` example above.
3. [using R >=4.3.0] use `if(as.Date(current_date) == "2025-01-01")` since `?as.Date.numeric`: "as.Date will accept numeric data (the number of days since an epoch) since R 4.3.0 also when origin is not supplied" (thanks @Tobo)

Comment: Many thanks indeed for doing this. We could add (based on `chr == dt   # TRUE`) that "3. use `if (as.Date(current_date) == "2025-01-01")`"  is equally possible. I wonder if that is not considered idiomatic somehow?

Comment: That produces for me the error "Error in as.Date.numeric(current_date) : 'origin' must be supplied"

Comment: So it's to do with the `as.Date(current_date)` bit, not the comparison between date and character. From `?as.Date.numeric`: "as.Date will accept numeric data (the number of days since an epoch) since R 4.3.0 also when origin is not supplied".  So looks like a version detail.