# Converting Dates to Julian Date

Tags: r, lubridate, julian-date

I am currently trying to do Theil-Sen trend estimates with a number of time series. How should I convert the Date variables so that they can be run in mblm package? The dates currently exist like so 'Apr 1981'. I want to use monthly medians in this assessment. See attached data.frame.

Thanks!

```r
mo   yr   doc   Date
04 1981 2.800 Apr 1981
05 1982 2.700 May 1982
10 1999 0.500 Oct 1999
05 2000 2.400 May 2000
06 2000 1.200 Jun 2000
07 2000 0.950 Jul 2000
08 2000 0.700 Aug 2000
09 2000 0.750 Sep 2000
10 2000 0.600 Oct 2000
11 2000 0.785 Nov 2000
12 2000 0.660 Dec 2000
01 2001 0.710 Jan 2001
```

Comment: Those aren't dates, they are `character` (or `factor`). See `as.Date` for converting it to a `Date` class object, and then `as.numeric` for converting to a number. Otherwise, possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21414847.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a date vector into Julian day in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414847/convert-a-date-vector-into-julian-day-in-r)